# androidx AlertDialog not working on device

Tags: android, androidx

Using the [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/material/package-summary#alertdialog) as is for `androidx.ui.material.AlertDialog`, it compiles ok but when run on the device, targetSdkVersion 28, it throws the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method AlertDialog$default(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Landroidx/ui/material/AlertDialogButtonLayout;Landroidx/ui/graphics/Shape;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Landroidx/ui/material/AlertDialogKt; or its super classes
```

Is it something to do with the API level on the device?

`build.gradle` has:

```
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev10'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev10'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev10'
```

`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` from [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialogs/) works but the example supplied by Google for `AlertBuilder` does not work.